# Convex reformulation of optimization problem with a bilinear constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\min_{x,s,\lambda} \quad J(x)\\
f(x)=0\\
\lambda^\top x \leq s\\
\lambda^\top e=1\\
\lambda\geq 0
\end{align}

where $x \in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{X}$ is a convex set, $f(x)$ and $J(x)$ are affine and quadratic functions respectively. $e$ is a vector consisting of all ones.

I know that the second constraint is a bilinear one. Is there any method to reformulate this problem into a convex program?

I have tried solving this using `fmincon` and other nonlinear solvers, but either I get an error, or the solution is not the desired one.

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that this problem is actually convex?

Comment: No, as long as I know, it is nonconvex. I would like to solve it either by just using a solver, or relaxing it into a convex one but without using big-M.

Comment: That's correct. Actually, I have more constraints, which are comparatively easy to handle.

Comment: Your last three constraints appear to be equivalent to $\min\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\} \leq s$ [after eliminating the $\lambda$ variables], so I'm not sure that there is a convex reformulation in general. There should be a MIQP reformulation though (depending on the function $J$ and the set $\mathcal{X}$, it might be feasible to solve this)

Comment: I don't understand how the last three constraints are equivalent to pointwise minimum constraint.

Comment: At any point $x$ such that $\min\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\} \leq s$, we can also choose the feasible $\lambda$ with $\lambda_j = 1$ and $\lambda_i \neq 0$, for $i \neq j$, where $j$ is an index corresponding to a minimum component of $x$.